# run sudo commands from gnome-extentions

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extensions

I want to run a sudo command that prompts a GUI for the user to enter their password and get the password back for future use.

running this in a gnome-extention

`GLib.spawn_command_line_sync('sudo echo e')`

I get the following error

```
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
```

Answer (score 1):

You should never be storing user passwords for later use or running privileged programs that spawn other programs, but instead prompting each time you need it.

To prompt for a privileged program, you can usually use `pkexec` in place of `sudo`. Additionally you should be spawning asynchronously with `Gio.Subprocess` whenever possible, as a synchronous subprocess will block the main thread of GNOME Shell.

Comment: Can I use something like GLib.spawn_command_line_sync('sudo echo e')  or does that have any draw backs ?

Comment: `sudo` will not work; there's no where for the user to enter the password. `pkexec` is the appropriate program for a GUI environement.